# Rx : Force observable to take at least N seconds to complete

Tags: rxjs, rx-java, reactivex

I am making a splash screen for my app. I want it to last at least N seconds before going to the main screen.

I have an **Rx** variable `myObservable` that returns data from the server or from my local cache. How do I force `myObservable` to complete in **at least N seconds**?

```
myObservable
// .doStuff to make it last at least N seconds
   .subscribe(...)
```

Comment: Adding `delay(new Date(Date.now() + 6000))` before the `subscribe` is another (somewhat simpler) option, as `delay` will accept an absolute `Date`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `forkJoin` to wait until two Observables complete:

```
Observable.forkJoin(myObservable, Observable.timer(N), data => data)
  .subscribe(...);
```

For RxJS 6 without the deprecated result selector function:

```
forkJoin(myObservable, Observable.timer(N)).pipe(
  map(([data]) => data),
)
.subscribe(...);
```

Edit: As mentioned in comments, `Observable.timer(N)` with just one parameter will complete after emitting one item so there's not need to use `take(1)`.

Comment: Thanks martin, do you know the `forkjoin()` equivalent in rxjava?

Comment: The take(1) operator is noop, considering that the timer will emit only 1 value

Comment: That's not true, `forkJoin` passes values from all source Observables into the selector so `data => data` is just a shorter notation for `(data, i) => data`. If you don't use selector the value emitted further will be `[data, i]`

Comment: For RXJS 6
`forkJoin(myObservable, timer(N)).subscribe(([val, _]) => {...})`

Answer (score 2):

Angular 7+ example of `forkjoin`

I like to build in a higher delay on my development system since I assume production will be slower. `Observable.timer` doesn't seem to be available any longer but you can use `timer` directly.

```js
forkJoin(

  // any observable such as your service that handles server coms
  myObservable,

  // or http will work like this
  // this.http.get( this.url ),

  // tune values for your app so very quick loads don't look strange
  timer( environment.production ? 133 : 667 ),

).subscribe( ( response: any ) => {

  // since we aren't remapping the response you could have multiple
  // and access them in order as an array
  this.dataset = response[0] || [];

  // the delay is only really useful if some visual state is changing once loaded
  this.loading = false;

});
```

Comment: I found the comments you put in the code very helpful, thanks.